# Vector of class pointers as a member of the class

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a class called node.

```
// Code

void
parser::parse_line(string line) {
    // Vector to hold the components of a line
    // It is just like an array
    vector<string> components;

    // Split on space and add to vector
    istringstream ssin(line);
    while (getline(ssin, line, ' ')) {
        components.push_back(line);
    }

    // Parse accordingly
    // If driver
    if (components.at(0).compare(driver) == 0) {
        Node* source_node = new Node(components);
        nodes.insert(pair<int, Node*>(source_node->get_id(), source_node));
    } else if (components.at(0).compare(candidate) == 0) { // If candidate
        Node *candidate_node = new Node(components);
        nodes.insert(pair<int, Node*>(candidate_node->get_id(), candidate_node));
    } else if (components.at(0).compare(sink) == 0) { // If sink
    Sink_Node *sink_node = new Sink_Node(components);
    nodes.insert(pair<int, Node*>(sink_node->get_id(), sink_node));
    } else if (components.at(0).compare(edge) == 0) { // If edge
        int parent_id = atoi(components.at(1).c_str());
        int child_id = atoi(components.at(2).c_str());
        Node *parent_node = nodes.find(parent_id)->second;
        Node *child_node = nodes.find(child_id)->second;

        parent_node->add_child_node(&child_node);
    }
}

    class Node 
    {
      protected:
        int id;
        double x_coordinate;
        double y_coordinate;

      public:
        // Constructor
        Node();
        Node(vector<string>& components) :
        id(atoi(components.at(1).c_str())), x_coordinate(atof(components.at(2).c_str())), y_coordinate(atof(components.at(3).c_str())) {}

        // Getters
        inline int get_id() {return id;}
        inline double get_x_coordinate() {return x_coordinate;}
        inline double get_y_coordinate() {return y_coordinate;}

        // Vector of child nodes
            vector<Node*> child_nodes;

        inline void add_child_node(Node* child_node) 
        { 
            child_nodes.push_back(child_node); }
        };
    }
```

If I initialize the vector outside as a member, I get segmentation fault when I am trying to `push_back` the child node. 
when I initialize the vector inside the function, it works but doesnt produce the result I need.

Comment: what is the result you need ? can you explain more ?

Comment: I need to add a list of pointers to child_nodes and be able to print it later. I call this function from my parser.cpp where I pass pointers of type Node to it.

Comment: I don't immediately see any error in the code above.  Could you show us the actual code that segfaults, and the contra-example that does not?

Comment: @user3068319 yes I understand, but you said it works so it adds pointers to the child_nodes, what is the wrong result then, where do you get wrong result? what is the result expected and what are you getting instead?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to create a tree, given some nodes and the edges that connect them. I want the vector<Node*> to contain the parsed tree.